# python 2.7 сравнение даты с текущей

Tags: python

Есть следующий вывод:

> ```
> имя1@8/28/2018
>
> имя2@8/30/2018
>
> имя122@8/30/2018
> ```

Подскажите, как сравнить даты в строках с текущей системой и вывести те строки, которые больше суток

Comment: Что значит число перед @

Comment: это число не относится к дате

Comment: *шаг №1:* найти строки, которые представляют даты во вводе. *Шаг №2:* распознать строку как дату (к примеру, в `datetime.date` объект превратить). *Шаг №3:* сравнить date объекты с текущей датой и найти те, которое больше суток назад¶ Какой шаг у вас сложности вызывает? Чтобы большему числу людей ответы могли бы пригодиться. Лучше по отдельности о каждом непонятном шаге спрашивать (можно упомянуть для контекста обрамляющую задачу -- это может повлиять какое именно решение для каждого шага выбрать)

Comment: Представьте, что есть ~1000 простых шагов, можно 1000 вопросов задать. А если вопросы по 3 каких-то шага из 1000 выбирать, то получится уже C(1000, 3) ~166миллионов разных вопросов можно составить ([C(n,k)=n!/(k!*(n-k)!)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Проще 1000 качественных ответов написать, чем сотню миллионов.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
date_list = ["name1@8/28/2018", "name2@8/30/2018", "name3@8/30/2018"]
today = datetime.date.today()
t = [x.split("@") for x in date_list]
for d in t:
    d_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d[1], "%m/%d/%Y")
    if today > d_date.date():
        print "{} was spent".format(d[0])
    else:
        print "{} is ok".format(d[0])
# name1 was spent
# name2 is ok
# name3 is ok
```